# Python n_jobs for large scale prob

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

When I use the parameter `n_jobs` in **`cross_val_score()`**.

It works well when my data scale is small, but as I enlarged the scale of my data, the `multiprocessing` seems don't work.

How could this be?

P.S.: I use IPython

Comment: Would you mind to revisit your post and review Answers provided to your Question and also click an [ Accept ] for the best one? This is a way StackOverflow works and how members reward knowledge sponsors and also help direct further readers.

Answer (score 4):

### `n_jobs` does the job and helps

Given your "small scale" `multiprocessing` experience was satisfactory, there is no reason for `n_jobs` to cease accelerating the actual processing on larger scales.

Machine-learning processing pipelines exhibit in many cases **O( N <sup>f</sup> )** polynomial complexity, where **N** is the number of examples in the dataset of observations ( X ) and the **f** is cited in various papers to be for various learning algoritms not less than ~ ( 2+ ).

As the dataset sizes grow, the time-to-compute expands polynomially.
Whereas even the `n_jobs` help can ( in most optimistic cases ) reduce that growth by not more than just by a constant factor of **`1 / { 2, 3, 4, .., 8, .., <max_cpu_cores> }`**
 <sub>( and yet this constant factor is further remarkably reduced due to [**Amdahl's Law**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) ( ref. Fig. below ), depending on how much of the work is possible to run in parallel on such `n_jobs` v/s  how much work yet remains just serially executed, irrespective of how many jobs one has set to launch and run. Tweaking O/S process priorities does some help, but large `N`-s still grow a lot, so the more The Time is Money applies here ).</sub>

Some additionally adverse effects come from a need to allocate replicated data-structures, so [PSPACE] adds to the already painful [PTIME] headaches.

Even the most promising ML-learners grow in [TIME] dimension of the complexity by **O( N log( N ) )**

---

## So, **`n_jobs`** always helps a lot,

you would have to wait way longer without using **`n_jobs`**, just try to run the same problem with `n_jobs = 1` and with **`n_jobs = -1`**.

Anyway, stay tuned. AI / ML-domain is full of **[ *TIME, *SPACE ]**, where **`*`** is not only polynomial, as you have experienced so far, but many times the exponential, so get ready to fight Dragons :o)

---

### Epilogue:

The good news is, that for advanced AI/ML-processing, the contemporary technology can provide infrastructures, that have reasonable amounts of TB RAM for fighting the [PSPACE]/[EXPSPACE] battle-front and at the same time efficiently harness thousands real CPU-s, so one can make **`n_jobs`** -- if research needs plus financing allows -- up to some large thousands of jobs!

Yes, large thousands -- so one can receive `scikit` results remarkably faster, than without harnessing such infrastructure ( and a Cloud is not the answer here ...  <sub>( do not hesistate to drop me a note if you need such high-performance infrastructure up and running for your large-scale problems, ok? )</sub>  )

( all that if Amdahl Law-view of the process-graph **possible Speedup** does make sense to scale )
[image]

---

### Pictures are nice,
 but see the absolute figures to "SMELL THE SMOKE"
[hr] v/s [min]:

```
>>> procPAR_SEQ_percent = 1.00
                         #100 % PAR:

                       n_jobs:    Speedup x|       [hr] =          [s] =        [min]
-----------------------------:-------------|------------=--------------=-------------
                            1:   1.000000 x| 3.000 [hr] = 10800.00 [s] = 180.00 [min]
                            2:   1.999985 x| 1.500 [hr] =  5400.04 [s] =  90.00 [min]
                            4:   3.999941 x| 0.750 [hr] =  2700.04 [s] =  45.00 [min]
                            8:   7.999763 x| 0.375 [hr] =  1350.04 [s] =  22.50 [min]
                           16:  15.999052 x| 0.188 [hr] =   675.04 [s] =  11.25 [min]
                           32:  31.996208 x| 0.094 [hr] =   337.54 [s] =   5.63 [min]
                           64:  63.984833 x| 0.047 [hr] =   168.79 [s] =   2.81 [min]
                          128: 127.939347 x| 0.023 [hr] =    84.42 [s] =   1.41 [min]
                          256: 255.757504 x| 0.012 [hr] =    42.23 [s] =   0.70 [min]
                          512: 511.030934 x| 0.006 [hr] =    21.13 [s] =   0.35 [min]
                         1024: 996.309963 x| 0.003 [hr] =    10.84 [s] =   0.18 [min]
                         2048: 996.309963 x| 0.003 [hr] =    10.84 [s] =   0.18 [min]
                         4096: 996.309963 x| 0.003 [hr] =    10.84 [s] =   0.18 [min]
                         8192: 996.309963 x| 0.003 [hr] =    10.84 [s] =   0.18 [min]

>>> procPAR_SEQ_percent = 0.99
                          # 99 % PAR:


                       n_jobs:   Speedup x|       [hr] =          [s] =        [min]
-----------------------------:------------|------------=--------------=-------------
                            1:  1.000000 x| 3.000 [hr] = 10800.00 [s] = 180.00 [min]
                            2:  1.980183 x| 1.530 [hr] =  5507.50 [s] =  91.79 [min]
                            4:  3.883439 x| 0.795 [hr] =  2861.23 [s] =  47.69 [min]
                            8:  7.476428 x| 0.427 [hr] =  1538.09 [s] =  25.63 [min]
                           16: 13.912327 x| 0.243 [hr] =   876.53 [s] =  14.61 [min]
                           32: 24.425271 x| 0.152 [hr] =   545.74 [s] =   9.10 [min]
                           64: 39.258095 x| 0.106 [hr] =   380.35 [s] =   6.34 [min]
                          128: 56.375891 x| 0.083 [hr] =   297.66 [s] =   4.96 [min]
                          256: 72.093421 x| 0.071 [hr] =   256.31 [s] =   4.27 [min]
                          512: 83.771055 x| 0.065 [hr] =   235.63 [s] =   3.93 [min]
                         1024: 90.961156 x| 0.063 [hr] =   225.54 [s] =   3.76 [min]
                         2048: 90.961156 x| 0.063 [hr] =   225.54 [s] =   3.76 [min]
                         4096: 90.961156 x| 0.063 [hr] =   225.54 [s] =   3.76 [min]
                         8192: 90.961156 x| 0.063 [hr] =   225.54 [s] =   3.76 [min]

 >>> procPAR_SEQ_percent = 0.98
                           # 98 % PAR:


                       n_jobs:   Speedup x|       [hr] =          [s] =        [min]
-----------------------------:------------|------------=--------------=-------------
                            1:  1.000000 x| 3.000 [hr] = 10800.00 [s] = 180.00 [min]
                            2:  1.960770 x| 1.559 [hr] =  5613.88 [s] =  93.56 [min]
                            4:  3.773532 x| 0.839 [hr] =  3020.80 [s] =  50.35 [min]
                            8:  7.017361 x| 0.479 [hr] =  1724.26 [s] =  28.74 [min]
                           16: 12.307131 x| 0.299 [hr] =  1075.99 [s] =  17.93 [min]
                           32: 19.751641 x| 0.209 [hr] =   751.85 [s] =  12.53 [min]
                           64: 28.315614 x| 0.164 [hr] =   589.79 [s] =   9.83 [min]
                          128: 36.153350 x| 0.141 [hr] =   508.75 [s] =   8.48 [min]
                          256: 41.960691 x| 0.130 [hr] =   468.24 [s] =   7.80 [min]
                          512: 45.625087 x| 0.124 [hr] =   447.98 [s] =   7.47 [min]
                         1024: 47.656029 x| 0.122 [hr] =   438.09 [s] =   7.30 [min]
                         2048: 47.656029 x| 0.122 [hr] =   438.09 [s] =   7.30 [min]
                         4096: 47.656029 x| 0.122 [hr] =   438.09 [s] =   7.30 [min]
                         8192: 47.656029 x| 0.122 [hr] =   438.09 [s] =   7.30 [min]
```

---

Last but not least, I run all AI/ML-engines from standard `python`, never from iPython in production. With `n_jobs = -1` and other acceleration tricks, still the global model-search and hyper-parameters optimisation pipelines span many days to robustly ge t to a best generalising model's global-minimum.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.But my true problem is, the n_jobs stops work when the data scale is too big. It creates sub-processes, but they don't work, occupying no CPU resources. Maybe it detected that my memory is not enough and stopped?

Comment: **[Step 0:]** run the same scenario outside of iPython ( IDE-GUI / core-engine(s) communication Watchdogs used to sometime hangup, that was why I stopped using iPython for large-scale jobs ) **[Step 1:]** profile memory-allocations ( O/S profiler or psutils ) for the hypothesis rough (contra)-indication